# Rxhttpclient proxy configuration in micronaut

Tags: kotlin, proxy, micronaut

I am currently facing an issue when configuring a proxy for RxHttpClient in micronaut. What I want to do is send a POST request to FCM through the API which is behind a cooperate proxy. Already tried the solutions in documentation. But nothing seems to work.

```
httpClient.exchange(POST("/fcm/send", param)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", "key=$serverKey"))
            .subscribe { return@subscribe }
```

In above code snippet httpClient is a RxHttpClient. This works without a proxy setting. Is there any work around for configuring proxy for RxHttpClients?

**Update**

```
micronaut:
 application:
  name: admin-api
 http:
  services:
   cloudMessagingService:
    proxy-type: http
    proxy-address: some.proxy.corp.com:8000
    urls:
      - https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Is this way of adding the proxy configuration correct?

Comment: "send a POST request to FCM through the API which is behind a cooperate proxy" - Is the issue that the API is behind a proxy, or that your client is behind a proxy?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown The API is behind a proxy.

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried.

Comment: "The API is behind a proxy" - I don't think any special config should be needed in your client in order to call an API that is behind a proxy.